# Fundamental group of $n$-punctured torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I think that very similar questions have been asked elsewhere on MSE, so if there is nothing new here I apologize.

I know that the fundamental group of the $n$-punctured torus is the free group $F_{n+1}$, as we can see by considering the punctured torus to be the wedge sum of of $n+1$ circles. My question is, what, geometrically, are the generators of the fundamental group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, of course, no canonical choice of generators, but here is perhaps the "geometrically simplest/most obvious" choice.
[[image: <span class=]$n$ punctured torus with $n+1$ loops" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACNtW.png)

Notice that if we filled in each of the punctures, each of $a_1$ to $a_n$ would be homotopic to the same loop $b$ and we recover the standard set of generators of the fundamental group of a Torus $\langle a=a_0,b\mid[a,b]\rangle$.